# If cell.value A = x, then cell.value N = formula

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, if-statement

Trying to fix my spreadsheet to paste a formula in column N, based on the value of column A.
Essentially, if cell `A6 = "Text 1"` then cell `N6 = "Formula 1"`, if cell `A7 = "Text 2"` then cell `N7 = "Formula 2"` then have this loop through all rows.

Very amateur at VBA, so excessive googling has given me the below.

```vb
Sub Test()
    lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

    For Each Cell In Range("A6:A" & lr)
        If Cell.Value = "Call Options" Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 13).Value = "=-(B6*100)*E6"
        ElseIf Cell.Value = "Put Options" Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 13).Value = "=(B6*100)*E6"
        End If
    Next Cell  
End Sub
```

At this point, I hit run and nothing changes. No error message or bug shows up.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: At this point, I hit run and nothing changes. No error message or bug shows up.

Comment: Check the value of `lr` and tell what it is. Also make sure to declare your variables proplerly (use `Option Explicit`). Then go through your code step by step using F8 to see what happens. There is the possibility that in your range there is no value `"Call Options"` and no value `"Put Options"` in this case the code does exactly nothing.

Comment: I also like to add some flexibility when comparing strings. [Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions), [UCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ucase-function), and [Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) can help when comparing user input strings.

Comment: Some progress! It was as simple as a capital letter! Should've been searching for 'Call options' instead of 'Call Options'
However, this is something I'd like to update as per each row, i.e. the formulas are intended to calculate values based on information in that row. However, they have calculated figures based solely on row 6. Time for some tweaking

Comment: See either my answer or @Pᴇʜ on how to handle the dynamic row issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to refer the cell in the same row you need to do this:

```
Cell.Offset(0, 13).Value = "=-(B" & Cell.Row & "*100)*E" & Cell.Row
```

If you want to make your `If` case insensitive use:

```
LCase(Cell.Value) = LCase("Call Options")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the code to the following:

```
Sub Test()
lr = Cells(1,Count.Rows).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 6 to lr
    If Cells(i,1).Value = "Call Options" Then
        Cells(i,14).Value = "=-(B" & i & "*100)*E" & i
    ElseIf Cells(i,1).Value = "Put Options" Then
        Cells(i,14).Value = "=(B" & i & "*100)*E" & i
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

The reason I would change this is you are just trying to find the last row, so let's not overcomplicate things. Also, when using numeric column values rather than alphabetical values, it makes it easier reference cells without relying on Offset.

Comment: I see no benefit here, actually it does exactly the same.

Comment: It works in the same way, just less text and allows for you to follow it numerically rather than alphabetically, which has its benefits. There is really no need for a Cell.Find in my opinion. Excel gives you a hundred ways to Sunday to do the same thing, for me its about doing it in the least amount of characters.

Comment: Actually `lr = Cells(1,Count.Rows).End(xlUp).Row` does something completely different than the OPs code. Yours does only look in the first column for the last data while the OPs code looks in **all** columns for the last data. • This might (depending on if the OP does additional things in his code that he didn't show) change what the OP intended to do. So it does not the same with less characters but something different.

Comment: But if you are matching off against something in the first column, why would I want more rows than whatever it is I'm matching off against? Seems excessive. I think we are splitting hairs at this point, and the code is more efficient if it only considers what it is checking against. But I agree with you that there was no issue with the Cells.Find as I had first considered.

Comment: I think you didn't see my point. Yes as I said it works for the code he shows. To be clear, nothing wrong with changing it. But telling in the comment it would do the same as his code might lead him straight into another issue. Instead it would be good to tell that you changed his approach to another way. At least he knows and can decide himself if it was a good decision to change it or not. Telling him it does the same with less characters just puts him into the wrong direction. Because it doesn't.